# SSRS report printing one row per page on Landscape

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have a report that is printing one row per page instead of printing enough rows per page. It's having every row that's coming from the dataset on it's own page. I have created a SSRS Landascape report, added a header and rows, clicked Advanced Mode and on the Header row I have the below properties

[image]

On the rows I have the below properties.

[image]

Report design

[image]

Is there something I'm doing wrong here or something I'm missing?

Comment: It sounds like you are using a row grouping. Can you post the report design?

Comment: @aduguid - I have edited and added the report design.

Comment: Open up that `GROUP` Property in the 2nd pic and then open the `PageBreak` property. My guess is the `BreakLocation` is set to `Between`.

Comment: Check the row group, "Details". If there is a group by column, that is probably the issue.